# How to find an ICC profile for a given printer?

Tags: printer, color-profiles

I'm trying to find an ICC colour profile (actually explicitly for a Samsung CLP 325W laser) but a) can't find the one I want and b) can't find a general resource for downloading them from. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every printer has them available - especially consumer level ones.  If the manufacturer has not made it available on the site, it's likely that none exist for that model.

I don't think colour accuracy on affordable colour laser printers is yet good enough to require ICC profiles, anyway.  I'm not even sure if it good enough on high-end colour laser printers, but I may be out of touch on this.